# Кросс доменная авторизация на yii2

Tags: php, yii2, framework

Всем привет!
Возникла такая проблема, нужно реализовать кросс доменную авторизацию.
Схема такая:
1. На первом домене(user.mysite.com) находится личный кабинет пользователя который работает на yii2 и через который будет проходить авторизация.
2. На втором домене(mysite.com) находится интернет магазин на "самописном" движке который должен работать с авторизированным пользователем. 
 
3. БД у них одна.
4. Лежат на одном сервере, в соседних каталогах.
5. должна быть реализована опция "запомнить меня"

Подскажите, можно ли это заставить работать? И как это лучше сделать?

Comment: вы написали ТЗ для фриланса, а не вопрос для SO, неужели в гугле не нашли ни одного решения, которое можно было бы попытаться сделать и написать тут что именно не получилось?

Comment: почему нельзя завернуть всё через одну БД (локалхост) и в нужных местах понатыкать редиректов на нужный сайт?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В конфиге

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => [
        'name' => '_identity',
        'httpOnly' => true,
        'domain' => '.' . DOMAIN,
    ],
],
'session' => [
    'cookieParams' => [
        'domain' => '.' . DOMAIN,
        'httpOnly' => true,
    ],
],
```

В index.php

```
defined('DOMAIN') or define('DOMAIN', 'mysite.com');
```

Куки будут общими для домена и сабдоменов

Answer (score 1):

Надо чтобы на обоих доменах совпадали

1. класс аутентификации, вероятно так и есть, если используются родные механизмы Yii;
2. домен, где сохраняется аутентификационная кука. в настройках сайта на под-домене укажите родительский домен;
3. база с пользовательскими аккаунтами. вы сказали, что БД общая - ок.

На всякий случай скажу:
Не тестируйте это на домене `localhost`. Браузеры чудят с куками на доменах первого уровня. Если надо испытать локально, заведите в hosts синоним для локалхоста, типа `localhost.com`.
Обратите внимание в настройках на точку перед именем домена, это каноническая форма!

См.
http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/install.cookie.subdomains
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378697/automagically-log-into-multiple-domains-in-yii2